# How to make `cd dir/filename` take me to dir/?

Tags: shell, cd-command

I would find it very convenient to be able to use `cd` with a **file** argument.

`cd myDirectory/anyname.anyExtension`
would be equivalent to
`cd myDirectory/`

What would be the best alias or function to achieve this behavior ?

**EDIT**:
Sorry I didn't mention it in the 1st place: I use `zsh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `zsh`, I often do:

```
cd /path/to/somefile(:h)
```

(`h` for `head`).

If `somefile` is a symlink, you can also do:

```
cd somefile(:A:h)
```

To get to the directory where the target of the symlink may be found.

---

The `zsh` equivalent of Chris' now `bash`-only solution would be:

```
cd() {
  [[ ! -e $argv[-1] ]] || [[ -d $argv[-1] ]] || argv[-1]=${argv[-1]%/*}
  builtin cd "$@"
}
```

---

In `zsh`, you can also redefine what "words" <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> removes.

In `zsh`, "words" in the context of the word-based motion/transpose/delete widgets  are sequences of alnums plus the characters in the `$WORDCHARS` variable which by default includes `/`.

You could remove `/` from `$WORDCHARS` so that <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> only deletes one path component:

```
WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
```

Another useful extension is the `select-word-style` widget which you can use to interactively choose between different word styles.

```
autoload select-word-style
zle -N select-word-style
bindkey '\ew' select-word-style
```

Then pressing <kbd>Alt-W</kbd> allows you to choose between different word styles.

```
$ cd /blah/blih<Alt-W>
Word styles (hit return for more detail):
(b)ash (n)ormal (s)hell (w)hitespace (d)efault (q)uit
(B), (N), (S), (W) as above with subword matching
?
```

Comment: Interesting. (I use zsh too).

Comment: Very interesting edit on the power of `zsh` and word styles. Thank you also for the `zsh` command. It does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you still want to retain the original functionality if you input a directory, and you are using `bash`.

```
cd() {
    local file="${!#}"

    if (( "$#" )) && ! [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        builtin cd "${@:1:($#-1)}" "${file%/*}"
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

If you are never going to use cd's options (`-P`, etc), then this will also suffice:

```
cd() { 
    if [ -d "$1" ] || [ -z "$1" ]; then
        builtin cd "$@"
    else
        builtin cd "${1%/*}"
    fi
}
```

Comment: if you change the function name to cd make sure to add `builtin` in front of the `cd` calls

Comment: @Chris: You assumed right ;) Thanks for this ready to use function

Comment: The version that preserves `cd` options does not work with `zsh`. The simpler one works fine with `zsh`, BUT `cd` is no longer equivalent as `cd ~` :/

Comment: @Sebastien Try now, I think that should fix that.

Comment: @Chris, indeed adding a check on `[ -z "$1" ]` was sufficient. I have accepted Stephane's answer to give it more visibility, as it seems to be the best solution for `zsh`.

Comment: This solution conflics with `autocd` option. I try this: `[ $# = 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ] && builtin cd "${1%/*}" || builtin cd "$@"`. It seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `dirname` to strip the filename from the path, e.g.

```
mycd() { cd "$(dirname "$1")"; }
```

See `man dirname`.

Comment: Note that if you input a directory, this will change to the directory *above* that directory, which may not be desired (it's unclear from the question whether this is desired or not).

Comment: @ChrisDown True, but I left that as an exercise to the reader and your answer shows how to deal with it.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth An exercise! Hah!

Answer (score 4):

If you add this to your `.profile`, then load it (`source ~/.profile` or log out and log in again), then `mycd [file or directory]` will take you to the right directory:

```
mycd() { if [ -d "$1" ]; then cd "$1"; else cd "$( dirname "$1" )"; fi ; }
```

If you name it `cd`, then strange things will happen.

Comment: This will break if the directory name contains whitespace, and you need a closing semicolon to terminate the command group. Edited it for you, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ChrisDown, though that's true of other shells, you don't need the closing semicolon in `zsh`.

Comment: Also, this breaks if passing args to `cd`, like `-P`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd2() {
 arg=() dir= cmd= IFS=" " msg='[-L|[-P [-e]]|-h] [dir|file]'

 while [ "$#" -gt 1 ] ; do
  case "$1" in
   -h) printf "%s: cd2 %s\n" "$0" "$msg"
    return 1 ;;
   *) arg+=("$1") ;;
  esac
  shift
 done

 [ -f "${1:-}" ] && dir="$(dirname ${1:-})" || dir="${1:A}"
 [ ! -z "$arg" ] && cmd="cd ${arg[@]} $dir" || cmd="cd $dir"

 if ! $cmd 2>/dev/null; then
  printf "%s: cd2 %s\n" "$0" "$msg"
  return 1
 fi
}
```

Comment: Given a directory called `$(sudo reboot)`, this function may reboot the system. Also, the user is using `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Give any command $(sudo reboot), this function will reboot the system. Also, +1 I didn't notice 'zsh' initially - good catch.

Comment: No, `cd '$(sudo reboot)'` would change directory, while your function would try to evaluate the name.

Comment: Ah, I see and made changes. Let me know if that works? Good catch.